# python- normalize nested json to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to normalize some `JSON` to flatten it for a `SQL` table. The problem I've come across is that everything I've read has a standard name for nested items but I am working with unique ids that I want to put in as values in my dataframe.

Here's a sample of the `JSON`.

```
{
"data": {
    "138082239": [
        {
            "id": 275,
            "name": "Sue",
            "abbreviation": "SJ",
            "active": true,
            "changedByUserId": "11710250",
            "statusUpdated": "2020-11-23T18:48:28+00:00",
            "leadCreated": "2020-11-23T18:48:28+00:00",
            "leadModified": "2020-11-23T18:48:29+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "138082238": [
        {
            "id": 276,
            "name": "John",
            "abbreviation": "JC",
            "active": true,
            "changedByUserId": "11710250",
            "statusUpdated": "2020-11-23T18:48:25+00:00",
            "leadCreated": "2020-11-23T18:48:25+00:00",
            "leadModified": "2020-11-23T18:48:25+00:00"
        }
    ],
```

I want to flatten this and add the index title (ex: 138082239) as a value `[LeadId]` in my dataframe. When I try to use `pd.json_normalize()` I just get a bunch of columns titled; data.138082239, data.138082238, etc.

I'm using `requests` to pull this `JSON` from an API.

```
    r = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    
    j = r.json()
    
    df = pd.json_normalize(j)
```

I want the dataframe to look like this:

```
LeadId      id    name   abbreviation   active
138082239   275   Sue    SJ             TRUE
138082238   276   John   JC             TRUE
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `dict` comprehension with `pandas.DataFrame.assign`:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v).assign(LeadId=k) for k, v in j["data"].items()])
print(df[["LeadId", "id", "name", "abbreviation", "active"]])
```

Output:

```
      LeadId   id  name abbreviation  active
0  138082239  275   Sue           SJ    True
0  138082238  276  John           JC    True
```